# Json Schema - oneOf with ref to wildcard path?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to organize the definitions section of my schema to group a number of similar definitions.  In the example below, I have an "ipAddress" group that has "ipv4" and "ipv6" sub-definitions.  (You could imagine adding even more sub-definitions for ranges of ip's that identify certain regions, etc.)

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "generalType": {
            "ipAddress": {
                "ipv4": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "address": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "pattern": "^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])$"
                      },
                      "generalType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "ipAddress"
                      },
                      "specificType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "ipv4"
                      }
                    }
                },
                "ipv6": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "address": {
                        "type":"string",
                        "pattern": "^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9]))$"
                      },
                      "generalType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "ipAddress"
                      },
                      "specificType": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "default": "ipv6"
                      }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": ["ipAddress"],
    "properties": {
        "ipAddress": {
            "oneOf": [{
                "$ref": "#/definitions/generalType/ipAddress/ipv4"
            },{
                "$ref": "#/definitions/generalType/ipAddress/ipv6"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to avoid doing is enumerating every single sub-definition in a `"oneOf"` property.

In other words, instead of

```
"oneOf": [
  {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/generalType/ipAddress/ipv4"
  },{
    "$ref": "#/definitions/generalType/ipAddress/ipv6"
  }
]
```

I'd rather do

```
"oneOf": {
  "$ref": "#/definitions/logicalType/ipAddress/*"
}
```

Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
References use json-pointer.

Besides, even if you could, you could not use `$ref` as a child of `oneOf`, because the value of `oneOf` must be an array.

`$ref` can only be used in place of a subschema, not just anywhere you like in your JSON Schema, according to the JSON Schema specification.

You can in stead create a new definition, like this...

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ipv4": {...},
    "ipv6": {...}
    "ipAddress": {
      "oneOf": [{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ipv4"
      },{
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ipv6"
      }]
    }
  }
  "properties": {
    "anIPAddress": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ipAddress"
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that you can't have multiple layers to your definitions. If want to separate definitions further, you can do so into multiple files.

Comment: That's too bad. I was hoping that there was a way to have a ref to a wildcard path that resolves to an array.  Oh, well.  May need to do some pre-processing on this schema.

Comment: You also cannot have multi level objects in definitions. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-9 - keys values of `definitions` must be JSON Schemas.

Comment: You COULD create a new definition which only has your `oneOf` inside, and then reference that.

Comment: that's interesting to find that nesting is not officially supported. If I go to https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/, paste in the above schema and validate `{"ipAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}`, it does validate it.  I think that it may still be a valid schema-- it may just consider "generalType" and "ipAddress" as "definitions" section.  (guesswork on my part)

Comment: Any JSON object with unknown keywords is a "valid JSON Schema" because additional keywords are allowed. In terms of `$ref` resolution, it can sometimes be sketchy in terms of defining what can and cannot be referenced. If you want your schemas to be safe for other implementations, they should follow the spec.

Comment: Also, recommend you try https://jsonschema.dev - It uses ajv and runs in browser. No posting your JSON schema and data.